# How to use xpath for multiple xml attributes in R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I would like to read some data from a xml file and embed these data into a R script so that I can generate a scatter plot. However, the problem is that one tag has several attributes and
I do not know how to handle that.
Please can you help me?

In the xml file below, I would like to read all results of the VertexConnectivity2, for example. Maybe my other question and the answers can give you a hint.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MappingTest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/ ./Alevin.xsd" xmlns="http://sourceforge.net/projects/alevin/" name="AdvSubgraphTestGenerator2">
  <TestGenerator className="tests.generatorTests.AdvSubgraphTestRunner"/>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="7.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="1612.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.6851389854194017"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.9861088559313271"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="0.7559889069056674"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="0.6648338346749284"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.279045304613785"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="0.4505067333055669"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="8.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="846.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.741814530894711"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="1.0019396461682453"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="0.868390100905683"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.854673959898261"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="1.295691487310222"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="0.6805885859898158"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="9.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="609.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.212517958069722"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.08677137867839191"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="1.9927278019276755"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.6370875136672722"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="1.8573960873462065"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="1.7266332660325572"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="578.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.145412191385898"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.826946783775961"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="1.8202071941911595"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.5890364574294114"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.2117994159315804"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="1.1993780131111107"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="11.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="797.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.3954850079335364"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.019578501527560466"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.0860109027715414"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.854555495387745"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.584217996538307"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="2.1648172533072234"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="12.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="892.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.4913004237744385"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.7696498939789347"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="2.201723978314626"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.04191205905592"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.376993537716656"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.034262661127799"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="13.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="872.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.047126232292386"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.9952229587725951"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.3794406500249257"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="1.6523543005400327"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.048441149178422"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.133358034963522"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="14.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="891.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.987660356945407"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.2484076205543828"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.9080988222890496"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.1670218484160566"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.2472187629267433"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.1328785000072386"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="15.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="1162.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.2234619923069414"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.45771183680269933"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="2.9215253413041196"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.054840069986192"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.442550183039827"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="3.995284651861695"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="16.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="1113.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.0926238844236447"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.7808319615152142"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="3.0087947748201787"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.1883371528470357"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="3.663210710605434"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="2.7728208750298773"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="17.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="2454.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="2.23606797749979"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="4.143188604518091"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="4.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="3.2916550003635034"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="4.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="2.7605883080698828"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="5.220399731228472"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
  <ScenarioResult>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_alpha" value="0.4"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Waxman_beta" value="0.5"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNodesPerNet" value="18.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumVNets" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="SNetSize" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_BW_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_BW_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Dem" value="10.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Dem" value="50.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Min_CPU_Res" value="30.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="Max_CPU_Res" value="100.0"/>
    <ScenarioParameter name="NumberOfRun" value="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="Runtime" result="2516.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="RejectedNetworksNumber" result="0.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity2" result="1.9840593925343335"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity2" result="2.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient2" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap2" result="0.3636812390986559"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric2" result="4.238514242266579"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="VertexConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="AlgebraicConnectivity0" result="2.2503830421805113"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="EdgeConnectivity0" result="3.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="FabianianCoefficient0" result="1.0"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="SpectralGap0" result="4.0227880048448625"/>
    <ScenarioMetric name="StochasticMetric0" result="6.649563197244915"/>
  </ScenarioResult>
</MappingTest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `xmlGetAttr` with `name = "result"`:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse(xData)
res <- doc['//*[@name = "VertexConnectivity2"]'
    , fun = function(x) xmlGetAttr(x, "result")]
> as.numeric(res)
[1] 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2
```

or alternative select the `result` attribute within the xpath:

```
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse(xData)
> as.numeric(doc['//*[@name = "VertexConnectivity2"]/@result'])
 [1] 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2
```

To "select NumVNodesPerNet = "14" so that I only have the value vertexConnectivity2 of NumVNodesPerNet = 14" you can break it down in steps.

1. Find the nodes with attribute `name="NumVNodesPerNet"` and that has attribute `value="14.0"`:

   `//*[@name="NumVNodesPerNet" and @value="14.0"]`
2. From this node go back to the parent:

   `/..`
3. From this parent node select the node that has attribute `name = "VertexConnectivity2"`

   `/*[@name = "VertexConnectivity2"]`
4. Select the result attribute from our ultimate node

   `/@result`

putting it all together we have:

```
myXpath <- '//*[@name="NumVNodesPerNet" and @value="14.0"]/../*[@name = "VertexConnectivity2"]/@result'
> as.numeric(doc[myXpath])
[1] 2
```

Comment: Thank you. Maybe you can also tell me how to convert the strings into float numbers and how to select  NumVNodesPerNet = "14" so that I only have the value vertexConnectivity2 of NumVNodesPerNet = 14 represented as a float.

Comment: You can convert the resulting list to a numeric using `as.numeric`.